# Oracle SQL Developer: How to display full column names in textual SELECT output

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Given this schema and data:

```
create table my_table
(
    my_key   number(8,0),
    string_1 varchar2(7),
    string_2 varchar2(7)
)
/
commit;
insert into my_table values (1, 'hello', 'bonjour');
commit;
```

When I `select * from my_table` I get this output:

```
    MY_KEY STRING_ STRING_
---------- ------- -------
         1 hello   bonjour
```

As you can see, the column names it gives me are:

- MY_KEY
- STRING_
- STRING_

I would like to see the complete column names in the text output (F5).  I know I can get the output in a nice grid (F9) with the full column names, but I want the **data and full column names in text**.

I would much prefer a solution which is not specific to this table and these columns.  A single solution which fixes the output for all my tables would be much preferred to a one-off fix to these 2 particular columns.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using SQL Developer v17.4. You have an option to choose how to auto-fit the column by right clicking on any column name.

Before selecting auto-fit:
[image]

After applying auto-fit:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with SQL*Plus? What you are asking has to do with SQL*Plus formatting commands. They work the same in SQL Developer.

Specifically:

```
column string_1 format a8
column string_2 format a8

<now run your query again>
```

Note that the `COLUMN` commands do not require a `;` at the end, since they are not SQL commands - they are not sent to the database, but instead they are interpreted and "executed" by SQL Developer itself.

**Edit**: Just noticed your last paragraph. No, unfortunately I don't think there is a universal fix. By default, the column width in the display is the width of the column in the database (the declared width for a base table, or the widest value in a column computed in a query); there is no way to override this default globally for all columns in all query results.

Comment: These commands work in SQL Developer too.  However, this would fall into the category of a "one-off fix to these 2 particular columns".  But maybe this is the best I can get.

Comment: lol - yes, these do work in SQL Developer too, that is what I meant - but re-reading what I wrote, I see how that could have been missed. I will edit again to clarify that. (I use SQL Developer too, for working with Oracle, and I use these commands to format the output when I need that.)

Comment: Another "fix" is to always declare your columns wider than you need to, but that has other side effects you may not like. You could also, in your queries, change the width of text columns (with `cast ( string1 as varchar2(8) )`) but that is more work than the `column` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Aliases?

```
Select My_Key, STRING_1 AS String_1, String_2 AS String_2 from my_table
```

Comment: First, what's the point of giving an alias which is exactly the column name? Second, how does that answer the OP's question, which had to do with truncating column names in the output?

Comment: In some editors giving an Alias will force a full display like OP has requested.

Comment: Oh, OK, I understand. Unfortunately, no, that doesn't work in SQL Developer or in SQL\*Plus.